# MongDB Aggregation with $project and $match

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents similar to:

```
 {_id:'12345', timestamp:41123412451, value:1000}
 {_id:'98765', timestamp:41123498714, value:2000}
 {_id:'11122', timestamp:41287364245, value:3000}
```

I'm running an aggregation query similar to:

```
[
{$match: {_id: {$ne: ObjectId('98765')}}},
{$project: { duration:{$subtract:[Date.now(),'$timestamp']}, value:1, _id:1}},
{$match:{value:{$gte:'duration'}}}
]
```

When I remove the second $match, I get all the documents, except '98765' (as expected). However, when I include the second $match, I get no documents. I have tried 'duration' and '$duration'. When I replace 'duration' in the second match with a hard-coded number value like 0, the query works as desired (by filtering out documents where value is not greater than or equal to 0).

```
[
{$match: {_id: {$ne: ObjectId('98765')}}},
{$project: { duration:{$subtract:[Date.now(),'$timestamp']}, value:1, _id:1}},
{$match:{value:{$gte:0}}}
]
```

It seems like there may be some "types" issue going on that mongo is silently ignoring and not returning anything... Can someone point out what I may be missing with the above aggregation method??? thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) aggregation stage does not work like that. Just like standard queries you cannot reference the value of a field to a query operator against another field. There are [logical operators for comparison](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-comparison/) and they are used with stages like [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/), like so:

```js
{ "$project": { 
    "duration":{ "$subtract":[ Date.now(),"$timestamp"]}, 
    "value":1, 
    "matched": { "$gte": [ "$value", { "$subtract":[ Date.now(),"$timestamp"]} ] }
}},
{ "$match": { "matched": true } }
```

But really this is probably better with [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) and "optionally" projecting your new field:

```js
{ "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
        "if": {  "$gte": [ "$value", { "$subtract":[ Date.now(),"$timestamp"]} ] },
        "then": "$$KEEP",
        "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
}},
{ "$project": { 
    "duration": { "$subtract":[ Date.now(),"$timestamp"] }, 
    "value":1
}},
```

So `$redact` works in a "logical" way in the same sense as `$match` works in a "physical" way, and can include expressions that can make a calculated value or direct field comparison on the document in order to "filter" content.

It is also basically handy that by doing it that way as the cost of the `$project` is really only limited to those documents that will meet the conditions, if you even need the calculated value in output at all, in which case you can skip it altogether.

Comment: @ossys Typo? I only saw "the the". Does that somehow make this invalid?

Comment: @ossys I think you might need to look at "edit history" on answers before you comment. Your comment "implies" that the `$redact` statement was "added" to the answer, but it was always there. All that was "added" was a paragraph of explanation as to what is happening. Note that this also does not obviate the initial `$match`, as that or another true "query" stage should always be the very first stage in just about any pipeline operations, as it is a true filter that can use an index.

Answer (score -1):

You have made a simple mistake in your 2nd match query.

```
 {$match:{value:{$gte:'duration'}}}
```

It should be :

```
{$match:{value:{$gte:'$duration'}}}
```

The '**duration**' is a variable generated by the 2nd stage of the aggregation pipeline. So it should be referred in the 3rd stage as '**$duration**'.